# How to use JavaScript variables in jQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use JavaScript variables as a parameter in a jQuery selector?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
  $("input").click(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr("name");

    $("input[id=x]").hide();    
  });    
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="bx"/><input type="button" name="bx"/>
<input type="text" id="by"/><input type="button" name="by"/>
```

Basically what I want to do is to be able to hide the element which has an `id` that is equal to the name of the element that is being clicked.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

```
var name = this.name;
$("input[name=" + name + "]").hide();
```

OR you can do something like this.

```
var id = this.id;
$('#' + id).hide();
```

OR you can give some effect also.

```
$("#" + this.id).slideUp();
```

If you want to remove the entire element permanently form the page.

```
$("#" + this.id).remove();
```

You can also use it in this also.

```
$("#" + this.id).slideUp('slow', function (){
    $("#" + this.id).remove();
});
```

Comment: It's important to note that the variable used to concatenate must be non-numerical, so do toString() if id is a number.

Answer (score 59):

```js
$(`input[id="${this.name}"]`).hide();
```

As you're using an ID, this would perform better

```js
$(`#${this.name}`).hide();
```

---

I highly recommend being more specific with your approach to hiding elements via button clicks. I would opt for using data-attributes instead. For example

```html
<input id="bx" type="text">
<button type="button" data-target="#bx" data-method="hide">Hide some input</button>
```

Then, in your JavaScript

```js
// using event delegation so no need to wrap it in .ready()
$(document).on('click', 'button[data-target]', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        target = $($this.data('target')),
        method = $this.data('method') || 'hide';
    target[method]();
});
```

Now you can completely control which element you're targeting and what happens to it via the HTML. For example, you could use `data-target=".some-class"` and `data-method="fadeOut"` to fade-out a collection of elements.

Answer (score 15):

```
$("input").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        $('input[name="' + name + '"]').hide();    
    });
```

Also works with ID:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$('input[id="' + id + '"]').hide();
```

when, (sometimes)

```
$('input#' + id).hide();
```

does not work, [as it should](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

You can even do both:

```
$('input[name="' + name + '"][id="' + id + '"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var x = $(this).attr("name");
$("#" + x).hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

`$("#" + $(this).attr("name")).hide();`

Answer (score 2):

1. **ES6 String Template**

   Here is a simple way if you don't need IE/EDGE support

   ```
   $(`input[id=${x}]`).hide();
   ```

   **or**

   ```
   $(`input[id=${$(this).attr("name")}]`).hide();
   ```

   This is a es6 feature called [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

   ```js
       (function($) {
           $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
               var x = $(this).attr("name");
               $(`input[id=${x}]`).toggle(); //use hide instead of toggle
           });
       })(jQuery);
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <input type="text" id="bx" />
       <input type="button" name="bx" value="1" />
       <input type="text" id="by" />
       <input type="button" name="by" value="2" />
   ```

---

2. **String Concatenation**

   If you need IE/EDGE support  use

   ```
   $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).hide();
   ```

   ```js
       (function($) {
           $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
               $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).toggle(); //use hide instead of toggle
           });
       })(jQuery);
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <input type="text" id="bx" />
       <input type="button" name="bx" value="1" />
       <input type="text" id="by" />
       <input type="button" name="by" value="2" />
   ```

---

3. **Selector in DOM as data attribute**

   This is my preferred way as it makes you code really DRY

   ```
   // HTML
   <input type="text"   id="bx" />
   <input type="button" data-input-sel="#bx" value="1" class="js-hide-onclick"/>

   //JS
   $($(this).data("input-sel")).hide();
   ```

   ```js
       (function($) {
           $(".js-hide-onclick").click(function() {
               $($(this).data("input-sel")).toggle(); //use hide instead of toggle
           });
       })(jQuery);
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <input type="text" id="bx" />
       <input type="button" data-input-sel="#bx" value="1" class="js-hide-onclick" />
       <input type="text" id="by" />
       <input type="button" data-input-sel="#by" value="2" class="js-hide-onclick" />
   ```