# How to use a variable in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

This works

```
$('input[name=nickname]').css(...);
```

Now how can I write the same but with variable ?

```
string[1]='nickname';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name=' + var_that_holds_the_name + ']').css(...);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use string concatenation:

```
$('input[name=' + string[1] + ']').css(...);
```

Although [technically](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) it should be both `$('input[name="nickname"]').css(...);` and `$('input[name="' + string[1] + '"]').css(...);`