# jQuery Selector equivalent of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the jquery equvaliant of this javascript

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("addcomment")[0].style.display = 'block';
```

but its not working

```
$('#+id+' '.addcomment').css('display','block');
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your string concatenation is wrong.

Comment: If you're using a code editor, then these sort of errors are caught/identified very easily by the syntax highlighting...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: Might be worth posting some html as you are getting some very presumptuous answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#' + id + '.addcomment').css('display','block');
```

as a sidenote in the page you should have only one element with that id, so

```
$('#' + id ).css('display','block');
```

should works too (of course only if classname it's not necessary to target it, since this is a different selector)

Comment: Your second example is incorrect as it will apply block to the `#id` element, not the `#id .addcomment` element.

Comment: Or `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.addcomment').css('display','block');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan of course they're different selectors. it's just to suggest another solution if classname it's not necessary to target that element

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.addcomment', '#' + id).css('display','block');
```

or just simple

```
$('#' + id).css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the child elements based on their class. So try this.

```
$('#' + id ).find('.addcomment').show();
```