# Trying to find a value doesnt work with a variable

Tags: jquery, input

IDK if I'm just overlooking something but i can get this to work:

```
var scu = 0291285;
$('input[value=scu]').val('changed');
```

nothing happens, but when i try:

```
$('input[value=0291285]').val('changed');
```

the input with a value of 0291285 changes.
will this method not take a var, and if so is there a work around for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not know about the `scu` local variable that you have declared. It thinks you want to look for an `<input>` whose value is the string literal `'scu'`. You want this:

`$('input[value=' + scu.toString() + ']').val('changed');`

Comment: Doh, I did that but didn't do .toString. Thanks.

Comment: `toString()` doesn't do anything here. when you concatenate to a string the variable is automatically converted to a string.

Comment: You are right, @PaulP.R.O., it appears his problem was the leading 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need `stu` to be a string to keep your leading `0`:

```
var scu = '0291285';
```

Then you need to use the [concatenation operator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) in your selector, to have the value that was in your variable be used:

```
$('input[value=' + scu + ']').val('changed');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[value=' + scu + ']').val('changed');
```