# Problems with jQuery code for select/option value selection

Tags: jquery

Hy guys. Any idea what could be wrong with that code:

```
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = document.forms["referentpodatki"].elements["id_uporabnika_ki_je_opravil_obisk"].value
$("#IDuporabnik option[value='$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil']:first").attr("selected", true);
```

It must be something with variable. If I use only second part like this:

```
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = document.forms["referentpodatki"].elements["id_uporabnika_ki_je_opravil_obisk"].value
$("#IDuporabnik option[value='37']:first").attr("selected", true);
```

It works. But no of this options resolved my problem:

```
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = "37"
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = 37
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = '37'
$("#IDuporabnik option[value='{$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil}']:first").attr("selected", true);
var IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil =  ....
```

Any help on this one would be much appriciated. THANK YOU!

Comment: JavaScript does **not** interpolate strings, you have to do string concatenation.

Comment: Make it $("#IDuporabnik option[value='" + $IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil + "']:first").attr("selected", true);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: You're using PHP syntax. It doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript isn't PHP, use `+` to concatenate. Also, you should use `prop` there, not `attr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = document.forms["referentpodatki"].elements["id_uporabnika_ki_je_opravil_obisk"].value;
$("#IDuporabnik option[value='"+$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil+"']:first").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: THANK YOU ALL! I used this, but there was a small mistake. Correct is:
$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil = document.forms["referentpodatki"].elements["id_uporabnika_ki_je_opravil_obisk"].value;
  $("#IDuporabnik option[value='"+$IDuporabnikakijeobiskopravil+"']:first").attr("selected", true);

notice .prop() and .attr(). It works now. Thank you again!

Comment: @NejcDraganjec So what have you used `prop` or `attr`? And what jQuery version do you use? If `prop` does not work for you, than your jQuery is too old.

Comment: I used attr. And have jQuery v1.7.2. Isn't that pretty new :)? Should I do upgrade?