# Is possible use a variable in jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

I have this code

```
var commentid=123456

var signature=($("#commentid_" + commentid).attr("data"));
```

but. It doesnt work... i get undefined.

Comment: If there's an element with that ID, and it has a `data` attribute, that will work. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/gU2Q9/).

Comment: off course i tried man...

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/ch2Lf/1/

Answer (score 0):

solved with..

```
$(window).load(function(){
[code]
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.load` on `window` when there's a perfectly good DOM-ready event provided by jQuery. Use `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` or shorthand `$(function () { ... });`.

Comment: where i can read about (function(){...})()  ?

Comment: It's in the [docs for the `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: yes. But there is a (function(){})() in pure javascript. Is there a doc for this to?

Comment: That's completely different. The jQuery shorthand `.ready` call is `$(function () {});`. Notice the `$`, and the lack of invoking parentheses.