# Using variable returned by ajax success into jquery selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function  which has a success block.  In this block I'd like to remove an element.

the success block contains the following :

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

$("#comment +$data['post_id']").remove();
},
```

I got an error  Syntax Error : unrecognized expression #comment +$data['post_id']

Where is the mistake ? how can I use the post_id contained in data ?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: `$data['post_id']` is this php variable ?

Comment: Actually, this is the better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5891840/218196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript variables are not referenced with a `$` unless you're dealing with jQuery-

Also, the variable cannot be in quotes. 
Furthermore, notice the array notation in the following snippet. I think both work in JavaScript, but it is worth noting.
Thus, if `data['post_id']` is the HTML `id` of the thing you want to remove - you would do this:

> success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
>
> ```
>  $("#comment"+data.post_id).remove(); }, // data['post_id'] should also work.
> ```

so that it is selecting something like the following, after the variable is rendered:

`$("#comment2").remove();`

Provided `data.post_id` renders into a number.

Comment: Java != Javascript >:-|

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah, i was trying to answer quickly fast.

Comment: Why haste? Proofreading doesn't cost more than the asker should be willing to spend.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Comment: the result I'd like to get is  #comment2  if 2 is the value of post_id  @rm-vanda

Comment: @rm-vanda check the accepted answer... SO isnt about reputation, it's about helping...

Comment: @sanfisa: Then do `$('#comment' + data.post_id)`. This is basic string concatenation and foremost has nothing to do with selectors. Maybe I should make this clear: Selectors are just strings. *How* that string is generated is irrelevant since jQuery will always only see the final string.

Comment: edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you don't think the final result was a well-written answer, then down vote. It took me less than 5 minutes to make it higher quality, and the only thing you two complained about was "Java" vs "JavaScript" which is ultimately irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @rm-vanda I wasn't complaining? I was arguing over the link you posted. You used a question to answer *"Why haste"* when the answer of this question is about quality. I though it was ironic. Anyway, not gonna start a debate on an other subject than the actual question.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear enough.  Post_id is not the id I want to remove. It has a value, depending on which post has been commented.  So, post_id is equal to a numeric value that I want to concatenete with #comment   @rm-vanda

Comment: Well, the only problem in your snippet was your quoting. You need to put the variables outside of the double-quotes. i.e. : 
`$("#comment #opinion"+data['post_id']).remove();` - does that make sense?