# How can I use a javascript variable inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a input parameter of a javascript function inside jquery command.

```
function logInEmail(value){
    var ati = $("input[name=" + this.value + "]").val();
    if(ati.length == 0){
        alert("Email cant be empty");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Just `value` instead of `this.value`?

Comment: var ati = $("input[name=" + value + "]").val();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've assigned `value` as the `logInEmail` function parameter, you can use:

```
var ati = $("input[name=" + value + "]").val();
```

instead of:

```
var ati = $("input[name=" + this.value + "]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "this" in javascript parameter variable as given below (`value` instead of `this.value`).

```
function logInEmail(value){
    var ati = $("input[name=" + value + "]").val();
    if(ati.length == 0){
        alert("Email cant be empty");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```