# Compare variable against test strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, sharepoint, text

Here is my JQuery Code and I would like to compare the text in the text variable "text" to the possible CR Status (e.g. Approved Implemented), but I don't know how to do it.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("colouring");

function colouring(){
    var $th = $("div[Name='CR_x0020_Status']").parent().css("background-color","#66CD00");
    var $index = $th.index();
    $th.parent().parent().children(".ms-itmhover").each(function(index, elem) {
        var $div = $($(this).children("td").get($index));
        var text = $div.text();
        $("text:contains('Approved')").css("background-color","#66CD00");
    })
}
```

I tried different options, but I still don't know how to do it!

Best regards and thank you in advance
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

You can't put variables in jQuery selectors. `$("text:contains(Approved)")` means an element with tag `text` that contains `Approved`. You could write:

```
if (text.indexOf('Approved') > -1)
```

But you don't need the `.each()` loop at all, you can do it all with jQuery selectors:

```
$th.parent().parent().find(".ms-itmhover > td:contains(Approved)").css("background-color", "#66CD00");
```

Comment: "You can't put variables in jQuery selectors." -- not sure this is relavent to the question, but you can. e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: That's not the same thing. That's using a variable to provide the ID in the selector, it's not searching the contents of a variable as the OP tried.

Comment: Oh.. I see what you mean.  Hadn't quite grokked it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you need, but possibly:

```
if(text == "Approved Implemented"){
    ...do more stuff here...
}
```

Possibly, you just need to duplicate the existing line and modify it for another colour:

```
$("text:contains('Approved')").css("background-color","#66CD00");
$("text:contains('Approved Implemented')").css("background-color","#0066CD");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! And if I would like to inject a .gif file dependent on the text. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, it's probably best to add it as a background image via css.  Long term you might want to add classes, rather than individual styles.

Comment: Where I can find an example how I can do this?