# How to find an ID that contains a string if the string is held inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be a very simple question in syntax but I've been googling and still can't find the answer.

I'm trying to set focus to the first SELECT element which has a specific string but the string is held in a dynamic variable. What would be the correct syntax? I thought the below would be correct but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('SELECT[id*=" + qID"]').focus();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('select[id*="' + qID + '"]').focus();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested and $('SELECT[id*=' + qID + ']').focus(); also works with less keystrokes.