# how to combine a variable with an ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello i have actually a quiet simple question,

I have a counter running (a) and want to select an id with the counter:
So if the counter (a) is "1", i expecte the ID #BG01 to be selected.
But it don't do it. What am i declaring wrong ?
i tried even +"a" to get a string but no.

Help please, thanks.
** Solved please see below the final code**

One question which came up during finalization: 
How can I pause the code for 1 sec, would like to pause the script while the top #BG fades in (not really a problem atm but you can see with a trained i the body BG for a split second, i assume thats because the script keeps on executing while css handles the transition so it would make sense to set it "onpause" for the time. i tried setTimeout but only with a length value it don't seems to work.. any ideas ? thanks

```
HTML:
<div id="container">
<div id="BG01"></div>
<div id="BG02"></div> 
<div id="BG03"></div> 
<div id="BG04"></div> 
</div>

jQuery:

var b=0,
    a=1;

setInterval ( function(){
if (b==0) { function() {
    $('#BG0' + a).css({
            "display": "block",
            "z-index": "10",
            "opacity": "1"});
    b=2;
    }
}
else {
    if (b===5) { function() {
        b=1;
        $('#BG0' + a).css("z-index", "1");
        $('#BG0' + b).css({
                    "z-index": "10",
                    "display": "block",
                    "opacity": "1"});
        $('#BG0' + a).css({
                    "z-index": "-99",
                    "display": "none",
                    "opacity": "0"});
        a=b;
        b=++b;
        }

    }
    else { function(){
        $('#BG0' + a).css("z-index", "1");
        $('#BG0' + b).css({
                    "z-index": "10",
                    "display": "block",
                    "opacity": "1"});
        $('#BG0' + a).css({
                    "z-index": "-99",
                    "display": "none",
                    "opacity": "0"});
        a=b;
        b=++b;          


        }

    }


}   
}, 5000);
```

Final working Code:

```
var y=0;
var x=1;

function divcycle(){
        $('#BG0'+ x).css("z-index", "1");
        $('#BG0'+ y).css({
                    "z-index": "10",
                    "opacity": "1"});
        $('#BG0'+ x).css({
                    "opacity": "0",
                    "z-index": "-99"});
        x=y;
        y=y+1;
}   

setInterval ( function(){
if (y==0) {
    $('#BG0' + x).css({
            "z-index": "10",
            "opacity": "1"});
    y=2;
}
else {
    if (y==5) {
        y=1;
        divcycle();
    }
    else { 
        divcycle();     
    }
}   
}, 10000);
```

Comment: please show your html.

Comment: `$('#BG0'+'a')` is not the same as `$('#BG0' + a)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: sorry my bet i played with it around to get it working.. the +'a' should actually be + a
was the remainder of testing sorry

Comment: the html is actually nothing special just some div's stacked.

    <div id="master">
 <div id="BG01"></div>
 <div id="BG02"></div> 
 <div id="BG03"></div> 
 <div id="BG04"></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing happened because your example was riddled with syntax errors. I fixed all of the errors and it seems to work alright now.

Try it out on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h1Lqcaex/3/

```
var b=0;
var a=1;

function setInterval(){
if (b==0) {
    $('#BG0' + a).css({
            "display": "block",
            "z-index": "10",
            "opacity": "1"});
    b=2;

}
else {
    if (b===5) {
        b=1;
        $('#BG0' + a).css("z-index", "1");
        $('#BG0' + b).css({
                    "z-index": "10",
                    "display": "block",
                    "opacity": "1"});
        $('#BG0' + a).css({
                    "z-index": "-99",
                    "display": "none",
                    "opacity": "0"});
        a=b;
        b+=1;


    }
    else {
        $('#BG0' + a).css("z-index", "1");
        $('#BG0' + b).css({
                    "z-index": "10",
                    "display": "block",
                    "opacity": "1"});
        $('#BG0' + a).css({
                    "z-index": "-99",
                    "display": "none",
                    "opacity": "0"});
        a=b;
        b+=1;          


        }

    }


}
setInterval();
```

Comment: thats what i first tried ->
    var a=1;
    $('#BG0' + a).css("z-index", "1");

so i expected #BG01 to be selected but nothings happens...

Comment: @NoZof I changed my answer. Does the JSFiddle link look like it works alright?

Comment: yeah it helped in the sense that i saw my errors that i made :) big thanks for that.
here is the working final code:
i edited the main post because in here i don't get the code to look like readable code ,)