# Find elements that end with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my searches I have found plenty of questions/answers on how to find elements that end with a **specific** string.  I've done a quick search and have not found anything specific about how to find elements that end with a variable.  I did find [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891840/34806) about how to use Javascript variables in jQuery selectors in general but I cannot get it to work and I wonder if it's because I'm trying to work against a set of elements I've already filtered down to.

Here are some id's of the elements I've already filtered:

```
["ms-goal-select-0", "ms-goal-input-0", "ms-goal-select-1", "ms-goal-input-1", "ms-goal-select-2", "ms-goal-input-2"]
```

And here is the (beginning of) the for loop I'd like to use to find and work with the select and input elements:

```
for (var x=0;;x++) { //will break when element(s) not found
    selectEl = filteredElements.find('[id$="select-' + x + '"]');
    inputEl = filteredElements.find('[id$="input-' + x + '"]');
    ....
```

But the above does not find the elements starting from the first iteration when `x==0`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `find`? Find only looks at *children* of the elements in `filteredElements`, not at the elements themselves.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That's almost certainly the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `filter` instead of `find`:

```
for (var x=0;;x++) { //will break when element(s) not found
    selectEl = filteredElements.filter('[id$="select-' + x + '"]');
    inputEl = filteredElements.filter('[id$="input-' + x + '"]');
    ....
```

Find only looks for matching children of the elements in `filteredElements`, whereas `filter` looks at the elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only searches in descendants. I think you want to do a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead. I'd write this using the version of `.filter()` that takes a function and use a regular expression to match the elements you want:

```js
var filteredElements = $("div");
var selectEl = filteredElements.filter(function() {
  return this.id.match(/.-select-\d*$/);
});
var inputEl = filteredElements.filter(function() {
  return this.id.match(/.-input-\d*$/);
});

console.log(selectEl.toArray());
console.log(inputEl.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ms-goal-select-0"></div>
<div id="ms-goal-input-0"></div>
<div id="ms-goal-select-1"></div>
<div id="ms-goal-input-1"></div>
<div id="ms-goal-select-2"></div>
<div id="ms-goal-input-2"></div>
```