# How to add string as jquery selector to chain function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i am checking parent id of the removal attribute.so how to merge this code with string.

```
var parentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
$("#"+parentId ".medicinetype-allergies input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: `$("#"+parentId + " .medicinetype-allergies input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');` Added **+** after parentId and a space before `medica...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Also add HTML, the issue might be of the selector

Answer (score 0):

That should works:

```
$( "#" + parentId + " .medicinetype-allergies input[type=checkbox]" ).removeAttr('checked');
```

**Note**: You missed the second `+` operator, which is used to concatenate strings. And don't forget to separate different selectors by space.

Comment: $("#"+parentId+" .None-allergies input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true );

Comment: How to make checked true

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure of '+' operator for your selector

```
 var parentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
 $("#"+parentId+".medicinetype-allergies input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');
```