# javascript variables in jquery selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bring the variable name inside the selectors, but its not working, 
here is the code, from where I have taken the example

[How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

and here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var detail = sample.one;
    var detail = sample;

    $('#' + detail).click(function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: Try var detail = "sample";

Comment: `var detail = sample;` enclose in `""`

Comment: which data sample contains?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the value between `"` because you want to store a `string` in your variable.

```
var detail = "sample"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var detail = 'sample';

    $('#' + detail).click(function() {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var detail = sample.one;
    var detail = 'sample';

    $('#' + detail).click(function() {

    });
});

<input type="button" id="sample" />
```

This is working.

`sample` is a string so use `"`

Answer (score 0):

create a variable with string value for example

var detail = 'sample';