# reactjs: alternative to nth-child (jsx doesn't build properly "child not defined")

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using gulp to build my JSX.

As of now I have react code that uses some jQuery:

```
this.setState({exceptionsEdit: manual_exceptions}, function(){
    this.state.exceptionsEdit.forEach(function (exp, index){
        $('#exception-list-edit').nth-child(index).find('.ui-slider').slider("values", 0, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[index].start)/1000)
        $('#exception-list-edit').nth-child(index).find('.ui-slider').slider("values", 1 , Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[index].end)/1000)
    })
})
```

I am setting the state of `exceptionsEdit` and then running some jQuery. But when I load my page i receive the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: child is not defined
         $('#exception-list-edit').nth - child(index).find('.ui-slider').slider("values", 0, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[index].start) / 1000);
```

What can I do about this? Should I not use nth-child? Alternatives that are jsx/react friendly?

Comment: You should not be using jQuery with react. What is the end goal your trying to accomplish? As in, what functionality do you need?

Comment: @erichardson30 I understand that. But this UI slider is a jquery library. This slider is the exception to the rule and I HAVE to use it. I am simply trying to update the sliders nob values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` is not a simple variable name as it contains `-`, so it can't be referenced with `.`, use `['nth-child']` instead. Btw I think it should be used like

```
$('#exception-list-edit:nth-child('+index+')').find...
```

since it's a selector, or with templates

```
$(`#exception-list-edit:nth-child(${index})`).find...
```

Comment: why the `+`s around index?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors, added the one with templates to the answer