# fadeToggle of many element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

please I want to apply  fadeToggle for each button but it does not work with this method ,I try to apply with this [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors) but not successful

this is Code HTML

```
   <div id="ajouter" class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button class="projetbutton">Projet</button>
                <form class="projet" style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button class="famillebutton">Famille</button>

                <form class="famille" style="display:none">
                    <input type="text" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is script apply  for the buttons

```
 <script>
var classElement = ["projet", "famille"];
var button = "button";
for (var i = 0; i < classElement.length; i++) {
    var classbutton = classElement[i].concat(button);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.classbutton').click(function () {
            $(".classElement[i]").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
}
 </script>
```

Please if there is another method to do that job.

Comment: Try $(".projet,.famille").fadeToggle();

Comment: Give a common class to all elements on which you want to trigger the event and then use it `jQuery`.

Comment: Or classElement.each(function(){ $(this).fadeToggle(); });

Comment: try `$("." + classElement[i]).fadeToggle()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: if I give the same class the forms display in the same time

Comment: Then use `$(this).next().fadeToggle()` inside the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the relation ship between element and various DOM traversal methods available to target element and then perform desired operation.

Associate the click handler using a common class, here used `classbutton` with the elements, then used `.next()` to get the `form` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.classbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajouter" class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="classbutton">Projet</button>
      <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </li>

    <li>
      <button type="button" class="classbutton">Famille</button>

      <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```