# jQuery: string interpolation in input selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select an input in my dom and I know it can be done like so:

```
$("input[value='foo']")
```

...but lets say we have a variable `x = 'foo'`.  How can I use that jquery selector with the variable.  I tried:

```
query = "input[value=" + x + "]"
```

but that results in `"input[value=foo]"` which is not the same.

**How can I insert my variable into this jQuery selector?**

Comment: `$("input[value='" + x + "']");` - Possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

You're close-- just missing those single-quotes:

```js
query = "input[value='" + x + "']";
```

**2020 Edit:**

Four years later, and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) enjoy support in every major browser except IE (which is on its way to deprecation).  Furthermore, by leveraging a build process with tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), you can transpile them for backwards compatibility with IE.  Thus, a more modern option like this is available:

```js
query = `input[value='${x}']`;
```

Comment: I thought it would throw off the string with only a single single-quote

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help!

Comment: Also, if you're not aware, single and double-quotes are functionally the same in Javascript, which is useful for when you need to do something like interpolate a value that needs to be wrapped in quotes.  You may already know that, but hopefully it is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = 'input[value="' + x + '"]';
```

wrap your variable in single quotes so the double quotes get added to the string.