# cant set radio element in html from jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

i need to  set radio element in user rating 5 star component.

get source from here (https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh)

i calculate user_rate from database data and need set it to radio element

second code is part of my .php code that dose not work;

first code is same code that only replace value with variable;

what is difference between two code?

first work and second dose not work :(

first code:(worked)

```
        <script>
        var user_rate=3;  //no need to this
        var $radios = $('input:radio[name=ratings]');
        $radios.filter('[value=3]').prop('checked', true);
        </script>
```

second code(dose not work)

```
        <script>
        var user_rate=3;  // value comes from database
        var $radios = $('input:radio[name=ratings]');
        $radios.filter('[value=user_rate]').prop('checked', true);
        </script>
```

Comment: You'll need to 1) Show us the DOM that you're running this against, 2) Tell us what you're trying to do, and 3) Tell us what "does not work" means.

Comment: Also note that there's no need for `filter`. Your first example is the same as `$('input:radio[name=ratings][value=3]').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this. You need to evaluate te variable and not pass it in the string directly.

```
$radios.filter('[value=' + user_r + ']').prop('checked', true);
```