# How can i use a variable in a Jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

How can I make this work? variable scope contains either Menu or Content. So i need it to find a input with the id `Scope_Menu` or `Scope_Content` depending on the variable scope.

```
var scope = $(this).data('scope');       
$('#frmEditPagevar').find('input[id="Scope_ + scope"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Use `$('#Scope_' + scope).prop("checked", true)`

Comment: `.find('input[id="Scope_" + scope + "]')`

Comment: Template literals - `.find(\`input[id="Scope_${scope}"]\`)` - much more readable to me https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.find()` because id attribute is unique in document and you can use jquery `$()` selector to selecting it.

```
$('#Scope_' + scope).prop("checked", true);
```

However if you want to use `.find()` change your code to bottom code

```
$('#frmEditPagevar').find('input[id="Scope_'+ scope +'"]').prop("checked", true);
// or
$('#frmEditPagevar').find('#Scope_'+ scope).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#frmEditPagevar').find('input[id="Scope_' + scope + '"]').prop("checked", true);
```

You were on the right track, just keep an eye on your quotes and double quotes

Comment: You really don't need to find :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. I will accept you answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it all depends if his IDs are really unique or not. Despite it should be unique and the other approach could work, that's not guaranteed, specially when classes and ids are generated by some kind of template engine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an id in hand, in an Ideal world, the below should work.

```
var scope = $(this).data('scope');       
$("#Scope_"+ scope).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should your code with my below code::

```
var scope = $(this).data('scope');       
$('#frmEditPagevar').find('#Scope_' + scope).prop("checked", true);
```