# Using JavaScript Variables with multiple jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is asked before for using javascript variables with the **Single** jQuery selector, As in this post below.

[How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

But my question is how to use one variable with two or more selectors?

```
var itemId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```

This is for one selector

```
var contentType = $('#' + itemId + ' .content-type');
```

But how to use `itemId` when i have two selectors in one row like below

```
var contentType = $('.content-type1, .content-type2');
```

Comment: try: `var contentType = $('#' + itemId + ' .content-type1', '#' + itemId + ' .content-type2');`

Comment: This does not work because the `,` must be inside the first selector

Comment: sure. i could not edit. but you got the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way, by adding a `,` between 2 selectors.

As of, you are doing:

```
var contentType = $('#' + itemId + ' .content-type');
```

For 2 elements, you use `,`:

```
var contentType = $('#' + itemId + ' .content-type1, #' + itemId + ' .content-type2');
```

Comment: I get an Syntax error from my editor, shouldn´t be the , inside of te string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concat manually as much as you need but maybe you can do a selector prepare the following way so you can append n-times the variable easily:

```
var itemId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
var selector = '#{i}.content-type1, #{i}.content-type2, #{i}.content-type3'; // you can extend this as much as you like or even add a loop to construct content types
var finalSelector = selector.split('{i}').join(itemId); // doing the replace
var contentType = $(finalSelector);
```

Where {i} is just a fictive placeholder string. I think this is a bit more readable. Anyways your question is kinda strange when it comes to the

> "or more selectors"

part logically. Maybe you need to change your code flow/implementation technique for whatever you are trying to achieve.