# Syntax error when using a JS variable in a JQuery selector for a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a lightbox and I'm at the point where I'm making next and previous buttons when the lightbox is in view. I'm using `console.log` to see if the correct `href` is being returned when the next button is clicked.

However, I want to use a Javascript variable rather than an HTML identifier in a Jquery selector. I've read that this is possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors), but am getting a syntax error when `next` is clicked.

The end goal is that when next or prev (once I get to it) is clicked, the next or previous image will be displayed in the lightbox.

Any help would be appreciated - or s

(please view the code snippet full screen)

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.gallery-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var image_href = $(this).children('a').attr("href");

    var image = '<img src="' + image_href + '" />';

    $("#lightbox").css("display", "block");
    $('#content').html(image);

    $("#next").click(function() {
      var images = $("#images-gallery a");
      console.log(images);
      var currentImg = image;
      console.log(currentImg);
      var nextImg = '<img src="' + $("#"+currentImg).closest('div').next().find('a').attr('href') + '"/>';
      console.log(nextImg);
    })

  });

  $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    $("#lightbox").css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
#gallery {
  width: 93%;
}

#images-gallery {
  display: grid;
  height: 250vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 2% 0 5%;
}

.gallery-item.one {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery-item.two {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.gallery-item.three {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery-item.four {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

#image-one {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/QPnhxMG/1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-two {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/mCvG6D5/2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-three {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vk9knm4/3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

#image-four {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/2qzmFC5/4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 30%;
}

#image-five {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/1GTpjvT/5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 40% 10%;
}

#image-six {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/1Ggs7Dc/6.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-seven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/TtTQHyM/9.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-eight {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/kXyt3Vh/8.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 60% 20%;
}

#image-nine {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/wsm2pzw/7.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-ten {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/p2P08Rn/10.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-eleven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/XX6rhVF/11.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 90% 20%;
}

#image-twelve {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/v4xTTPg/12.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}

#image-thirteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/5cc16kW/13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

#image-fourteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/C6QYn2C/14.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 30%;
}

#image-fifteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/d5hcyQQ/15.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-sixteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/VptGL3g/16.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 10% 20%;
}

#image-seventeen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vPjwYZg/17.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 30% 20%;
}

#image-eighteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vkpXpB0/18.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#allcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#lightbox ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightbox ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gallery">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Gallery.</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="images-gallery" class="fade">
    <div id="image-one" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/Xz6yLB5/Fencing.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-two" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/mCvG6D5/2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-three" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vk9knm4/3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-four" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/2qzmFC5/4.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-five" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/1GTpjvT/5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-six" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/1Ggs7Dc/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-seven" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/TtTQHyM/9.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eight" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/kXyt3Vh/8.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-nine" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/wsm2pzw/7.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-ten" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/p2P08Rn/10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eleven" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/XX6rhVF/11.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-twelve" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/v4xTTPg/12.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-thirteen" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/5cc16kW/13.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-fourteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/C6QYn2C/14.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-fifteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/d5hcyQQ/15.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-sixteen" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/VptGL3g/16.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-seventeen" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vPjwYZg/17.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eighteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vkpXpB0/18.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="lightbox">
  <div id="allcontent">
    <div id="content">
      <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li id="prev">Previous</li>
      <li id="next">Next</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lightbox provides the feature of relation like you just need to add `rel` attribute on a tag like `<a rel="">` it depends on which lightbox jquery you used

Comment: Hey man, I'm making a lightbox from scratch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using index value for next and previous click.

```js
 

  
 $(document).ready(function($) {
          $('.gallery-item').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var image_href = $(this).children('a').attr("href");
              var image = '<img src="' + image_href + '" />';
              $("#lightbox").css("display", "block");
              $('#content').html(image);
              
              $("#next").click(function() {
                  var images = $("#images-gallery a");
                  if (thisIndex >= (images.length - 1)) {
                      //alert("if")
                      thisIndex = 0;
                  } else if (thisIndex < images.length) {
                      thisIndex = (thisIndex + 1);
                    //alert("else")
                  }
                  var nn = $(images).eq(thisIndex).attr("href");
                  var nnImg = '<img src="' + nn + '" />';
                  $('#content').html(nnImg);
                  //alert(nnImg)
              });
              
              $("#prev").click(function() {
                  var images = $("#images-gallery a");
                  if (thisIndex <= 0) {
                      thisIndex = (images.length - 1);
                  } else if (thisIndex > 0) {
                      thisIndex = (thisIndex - 1);
                  }
                  var pr = $(images).eq(thisIndex).attr("href");
                  var prImg = '<img src="' + pr + '" />';
                  $('#content').html(prImg);
                  //alert(prImg)
              });
              var thisIndex = $(this).index();
              
          });

  $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    //$("#lightbox").css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
#gallery {
  width: 93%;
}

#images-gallery {
  display: grid;
  height: 250vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 2% 0 5%;
}

.gallery-item.one {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery-item.two {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.gallery-item.three {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.gallery-item.four {
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

#image-one {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/QPnhxMG/1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-two {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/mCvG6D5/2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-three {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vk9knm4/3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

#image-four {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/2qzmFC5/4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 30%;
}

#image-five {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/1GTpjvT/5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 40% 10%;
}

#image-six {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/1Ggs7Dc/6.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-seven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/TtTQHyM/9.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-eight {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/kXyt3Vh/8.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 60% 20%;
}

#image-nine {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/wsm2pzw/7.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-ten {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/p2P08Rn/10.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#image-eleven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/XX6rhVF/11.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 90% 20%;
}

#image-twelve {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/v4xTTPg/12.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}

#image-thirteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/5cc16kW/13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

#image-fourteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/C6QYn2C/14.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 30%;
}

#image-fifteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/d5hcyQQ/15.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-sixteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/VptGL3g/16.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 10% 20%;
}

#image-seventeen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vPjwYZg/17.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 30% 20%;
}

#image-eighteen {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vkpXpB0/18.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 20%;
}

#allcontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#lightbox ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightbox ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gallery">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Gallery.</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="images-gallery" class="fade">
    <div id="image-one" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/Xz6yLB5/Fencing.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-two" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/mCvG6D5/2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-three" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vk9knm4/3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-four" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/2qzmFC5/4.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-five" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/1GTpjvT/5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-six" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/1Ggs7Dc/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-seven" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/TtTQHyM/9.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eight" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/kXyt3Vh/8.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-nine" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/wsm2pzw/7.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-ten" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/p2P08Rn/10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eleven" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/XX6rhVF/11.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-twelve" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/v4xTTPg/12.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-thirteen" class="gallery-item two">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/5cc16kW/13.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-fourteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/C6QYn2C/14.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-fifteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/d5hcyQQ/15.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-sixteen" class="gallery-item three">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/VptGL3g/16.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-seventeen" class="gallery-item four">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vPjwYZg/17.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eighteen" class="gallery-item one">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/vkpXpB0/18.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="lightbox">
  <div id="allcontent">
    <div id="content">
      <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li id="prev">Previous</li>
      <li id="next">Next</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var images = $("#images-gallery a")` returns a list of HTML elements, as you're no doubt aware.

But looks like when you call it later as a source..

```
$("#"+currentImg)
```

...you're just prepending an octothorpe to HTML.

Comment: Have a look at my question again buddy. I included a link to another SO post that states you can prepend an octothorpe to a JS variable to be able to use it as a JQuery selector.

Comment: Right, but you're prepending an octorthorpe to an HTML string, rather than a recognized selector. I copied your code to Codepen and got the following syntax error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<img src="https://i.ibb.co/2qzmFC5/4.jpg" />`

Comment: Right, I understand. I thought by using that logic, when I click next, that would give me the `href` of currentImg, then the following JQuery selectors would give an output of the next divs `a href`?