# Trouble setting value of select input from success function of getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with a select input that is being used to filter a getJSON request in a function.  In the success function of the request, I am dynamically creating an html table from the JSON and appending the table to a div in the html document.  All is working fine, but the select input resets back to the default upon calling the function.

I am trying to set the select input back to the selected value so the end user know what data they are looking at.  I have the class name of the select input stored in a parameter called p1Name and the selected value stored in a parameter called p1.

Normally I would use something like this: `$('.ddlUserID').Val(p1);` where the class name is hard coded in. But I need this function to be dynamic and need to use the parameter of p1Name for the class name.  So I have tried:

```
var DDL1 = "'." + p1Name + "'";
$(DDL1).val(p1);
```

This returns the following error, Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.ddlUserID'. I have also tried the javascript syntax of `document.getElementsByClassName(DDL1).value = p1;` which returns the same error.

If I change the parameter of DDL1 to the hard coded value of '.ddlUserID' the form works as expected.

What is the proper way to set the selected value of a select input when using a parameter as the id or class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add extra quotation marks to your selector string.

```
var DDL1 = "." + p1Name;
$(DDL1).val(p1);
```

This should work

Comment: Yet are not the extra quotation marks required when hard coding an Id or Class name?

Comment: When you are 'hard coding' as you say, you pass a string variable which is represented as a concatenation of characters between single or double quotes (`'` or `"`). In your case, you where using both, so inside your string (which was delimeted by double quotes) there was the `'` character on both ends causing the selector to not be recognized.

Comment: The quotation marks are only necessary to indicate that something is a string, rather than being javascript code. Presumably `p1Name` is already a string, and so all you need to do is add a `.` to the front of it. Addition `+` on strings combines them into a single string, ergo `"." + p1Name` creates the string with a value of `.ddlUserID`

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the extra quotes in `var DDL1 = "'." + p1Name + "'";`

Should be `var DDL1 = '.' + p1Name;`

Answer (score 0):

It should work, you can use strings in the selector. **I think you don't need the single quotes**

```js
var p1Name = 'ddlUserID'
var selector1 = `.${p1Name}`

var selector2 = '.' + p1Name

console.log('selector1:', $(selector1))
console.log('selector2:', $(selector2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ddlUserID">ddlUserID</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.val()` in JQuery to set the value of select inputs.

> What is the proper way to set the selected value of a select input when using a parameter as the id or class name?

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891929/11860085.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var p1 = "foo";
  var p2 = "bar";
  
  var p1name = "some_id";
  var p2name = "some_class";

  $( "#setValues" ).click(function() {
    $('#' + p1name).val(p1);
    $('.' + p2name).val(p2);
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="setValues">Set values</button>

<select id="some_id">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>

<select class="some_class">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select something...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```