# JQuery: Hide all images except one, starting from the first one and scrolling it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I can't change the HTML code, and it looks like this:

```
<div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-control">
                <button id="prev">Previous</button>
                <button class="foll">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="html.png" alt="Html" />
                <img src="css.png" alt="Css" />
                <img src="jquery.png" alt="jQuery" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

When the program starts I need to show the first image. If I click on "Previous" I want to show the previous img (if the currently img showed is the first one, I want to show the last one), if I click on "Next" then I want to show the next img.
I need it to be a generic solution case I need to use it also with more images.
I tried with:

```js
function showImage(){
    $(".slider-image img").not(":eq(n)").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    n = 0;
    showImage(n);
    $(".slider-control button").click(function(){

        if($(this).is("div.slider-control.prev")){
            n -= 1;
            showImage(n);
        }
        else if($(this).is("div.slider-control.foll")){
            n += 1;
            showImage(n);
        }   
    });
});
```

But it doesn't show anything

Comment: `:eq(n)` isn’t a valid selector. You’re not using your variable `n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript variables in jQuery selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

There was a few issues that I've fixed for you, but this should now work okay for you

---

`showImage` was not taking `n` as a paramater, but you were passing it that when you were calling it

```js
function showImage() {... // Not taking the param you're passing
function showImage(n) {... // Now we are, and assigning it the name 'n'
```

You weren't using `.show()` on the element you wanted to show - you were only ever using `.hide()`

There was also an issue with how spamming the `next` or `previous` buttons would change the `n` higher / lower than your element count, and so you would end up selecting elements that didn't exist. To keep your `n` within the range of your elements, you can do this to loop back around an array's indexes

```js
n = n % $('.slider-image img').length;
```

Finally, you weren't passing `n` to the `:not(:eq(n))` - I've just used template literals to insert the variable cleanly

---

In the HTML, I set your buttons to both use IDs, because I felt this made more sense and helps readabilit

---

In the `$(document).ready(...`, you also had an error with your `.is()` - You were alredy working from the `<button>` element, so you're okay to check just on the ID of the buttons

```js
function showImage(n){
    n = n % $(".slider-image img").length;
    $(".slider-image img").not(`:eq(${n})`).hide();
    $(".slider-image img").eq(n).show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    n = 0;
    showImage(n);
    
    $(".slider-control button").click(function(){
        if($(this).is("#prev")){
            n -= 1;
            showImage(n);
        }
        else if($(this).is("#foll")){
            n += 1;
            showImage(n);
        }   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-control">
    <button id="prev">Previous</button>
    <button id="foll">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Html" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Css" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="jQuery" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you update the HTML & `.is()` queries like I had in the example snippet?

Comment: @SaraBriccoli Was this the issue, or is there anything else I could try and help with?