# jQuery - variable instead of table id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatable

How to use a variable instead of a table id?

For example, I want to replace the id `#myTable` with the variable `table`.

```js
function findFruitColor(table, fruit) {


  let colKey = $("#myTable th:contains('Fruit')").index();
  let colVal = $("#myTable th:contains('Color')").index();

  $('#myTable tr td:nth-child(' + (colKey + 1) + ')').each(function() {

    if ($(this).text() === fruit) {
      color = $(this).siblings('td').addBack().eq(colVal).text();
      return false;
    }

  })


  // Display the color that was found 
  if (typeof color !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("The color for " + fruit + " is " + color);
  }


}

// Call the function
findFruitColor("#myTable", "apple");
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 11em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL7zmhen/)

Comment: `$(table).find("tr ...")...` (also, provided that `table` is an id in string format, you can always do `$(table + " th ...")` but that's not good practice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JavaScript variables in jQuery selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891840/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks but not quite. Your comment and the answer were both clearer. Maybe this question was specific to the find() method. For example, going from a hardcoded tableID—$("#id tr...")—to variable as seen here—$(table).find("tr...") requires us to add .find().That was the missing piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The modern way

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
let colKey = $(`${table} th:contains('Fruit')`).index();
```

Template literals save you alot of headache regarding the escaping of quotation characters. Find the browser support for this [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals).

#### The old way (which you're already using in your code example):

Use string concatenation:

```
let colKey = $(table + " th:contains('Fruit')").index();
```